# Not able to check if child exists in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have looked everywhere for the solution, but I haven't found any. I have a problem with checking if a child exists on Firebase. On my case, for every unique user I am creating a sixDigitCode the first time he opens the app. So everytime I create this sixDigitCode, I want to check if the sixDigitCode already exists on Firebase. So if exists I can create a new one and do that so until the sixDigitCode is unique. So far I have written this code. But it ends up on endless loop of producing infinite number of sixDigitCode, and the onDataChanged is never called. Can you please help me? Thank you.

```
boolean itDoesntExist;

String sixDigitCode;

void addNewUserOnFb() {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference users = database.getReference("users");


    do {

        sixDigitCode = getSixDigitCode(); //Function that returns random six digit code


    users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasChild(sixDigitCode)) {
                // run some code

                itDoesntExist = false;

            } else {

                itDoesntExist = true;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    } while (itDoesntExist == false)


    //Do some more code

}
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand that Firebase is asynchronous. Any loop outside an event listener will not be ran in the same thread or in order of the event itself

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! So do you have any suggestion?? Because I even tried to use a completion listener but i didn't manage to find a way to use it.

Comment: Forget about the loop for a minute. Where are you adding data to Firebase? Does one invocation of the if else statement work as expected? I'm guessing it's hard to know because you're creating a random 6 digit value, and collisions are highly unlikely

Comment: After removing the loop and some debugging, I found that onDataChange is not even called. I even hardcoded a sixDigitCode that exists and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use UIDs as keys inside  users node or their email formatted so that it can be a valid key for database something like this :

```
String key = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".","_").replace("@","_");
```

**Assumed that you are using Firebase auth and allow only authenticated users to write to your database**

**You seem to be confused about Asynchronous Method of Firebase. Have a look at Docs**

You can check if a user exists or not by this :

```
ref.child(key).addSingleValueEventListener(listener);
```

And Listener is a instance of ValueEventListener. In which you will override

```
@Override
onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap){
if(snap.exists()){
  //Your user exist no need to create one.
}
else{
//do your logic
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On one hand I put an Asyncronous execution on a loop, but the reason I the onDataChanged wasn't called is that I didn't have the read available to public. So many hours for that detail. Now it's working fine. Thank you for your responses! Problem solved.